# INVALID T_TERMINAL_NUMBER sagepay

Tags: php, opayo

I am trying to test segapay in test page but its throwing an error

X911911INVALID T_TERMINAL_NUMBER 00P 0000000000000
X911911INVALID T_TERMINAL_NUMBER 00P 0000000000000X911911INVALID T_TERMINAL_NUMBER 00P 0000000000000

Approval Indicator: X
Approval/Error Code: 911911
Approval/Error Message: INVALID T_TERMINAL_NUMBER 
Front-End Indicator: 00
CVV Indicator: P
AVS Indicator: 
Risk Indicator: 00
Reference: 0000000000
Order Number:

```
 <?php


    // Marchant ID

    $mid    = "713558155666";
    $mkey   = "J1M3S4C5N5E9";


    $amount = "10.00";
    $cardholder_name = "Brijesh";
    $billing_address = "Test";
    $billing_state = "AL";
    $billing_city = "Test";
    $cardnumber = "5555555555554444";
    $exp_Date = "1109";
    $billing_zip = "12345";
    $email_addr = "brijesss@xxx.com";
    $ordernum = "3333333";

    //set the URL that will be posted to.
    $eftsecure_url = "https://www.sagepayments.net/cgi-bin/eftbankcard.dll?transaction";
    //make your query.
    $data = "m_id=" . $mid; //your eftsecure merchant id.
    $data .= "&m_key=" . $mkey; // your eftsecure merchant key;
    $data .= "&T_amt=" . urlencode($amount); // The amount to be charged. Always encode
    // any data given to you over the web. it is more
    // secure and reliable.
    $data .= "&C_name=" . urlencode($cardholder_name);
    $data .= "&C_address=" . urlencode($billing_address);
    $data .= "&C_state=" . urlencode($billing_state);
    $data .= "&C_city=" . urlencode($billing_city);
    $data .= "&C_cardnumber=" . urlencode($cardnumber);
    $data .= "&C_exp=" . urlencode($exp_Date);
    $data .= "&C_zip=" . urlencode($billing_zip);
    $data .= "&C_email=" . urlencode($email_addr);
    $data .= "&T_code=02"; // transaction type indicator
    $data .= "&T_ordernum=" . urlencode($ordernum);

    //HTTPS Bankcard Specifications 18
    //now we will make the transaction. the first method is the preferred internal method
    //using the built in CURL functions.

    $ch = curl_init(); //initialize the CURL library.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $eftsecure_url); // set the URL to post to.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // tell it to POST not GET (you can GET but POST is
    //preferred)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // set the data to be posted.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // this tells the library to return the
    // data to you instead of writing it to
    // a file
    $res = curl_exec($ch); // make the post.
    curl_close($ch); // shut down the curl library.
    echo $res . "<br>\n"; // this is the response.

    // or you can also use the curl executable directly.
    $curl = "/usr/bin/curl"; // the location of the curl executable.
    $fp=popen("$curl --data \"$data\" $eftsecure_url","r"); // this allows you to get the
    // data directly from curl

    while(!feof($fp)) $res .= fread($fp, 1024); // read all the output.
    pclose($fp); // close the connection to curl.
    //HTTPS Bankcard Specifications 19

    echo "$res" . "<br>\n"; // this is the response.
    // once you have the response then you need to parse its different components.
    echo "<br><hr><br>\n";
    echo "Approval Indicator: " . $res[1] . "<br>"; //A is approved E is 

declined/error.
echo "Approval/Error Code: " . substr($res, 2, 6) . "<br>\n";
echo "Approval/Error Message: " . substr($res, 8, 32) . "<br>\n";
echo "Front-End Indicator: " . substr($res, 40, 2) . "<br>\n";
echo "CVV Indicator: " . $res[42] . "<br>\n";
echo "AVS Indicator: " . $res[43] . "<br>\n";
echo "Risk Indicator: " . substr($res, 44, 2) . "<br>\n";
echo "Reference: " . substr($res, 46, 10) . "<br>\n";
echo "Order Number: " . substr($res, strpos($res, chr(28)) + 1,strrpos($res, chr(28) - 1)) . "<br>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Of course those aren't your real merchant id and key. Please say yes, because the internet is forever.

Comment: how can i use  segepay  test with testing details?